# How can i limit the number of articles (retrieved from an RSS) shown in php per page ? (Eg 10 articles per page)

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, rss

Here is the code :
I retrieve data from an RSS and i show them in a php page.
These data are items (Articles) which contains title, date, description ... Now i want to show just 10 articles per page.
Please how can i do that.
Thank you

```
 <?php 


    $fichier = 'http://korben.info/feed';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $slashNS = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/";


    if (!$dom->load($fichier)) {
        die('Impossible to load the XML');
    }

    $itemList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');


    foreach ($itemList as $item) {
        $titre = $item->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $date = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate');

            if ($titre->length > 0) {
                 echo $titre->item(0)->nodeValue;
              } else {
                 echo '(sans titre)';
        }

         echo date (" d/m/Y - H:i", strtotime($date->item(0)->nodeValue))."\t";
             echo '<br />' . 'Nmber of comments : ' . $item->getElementsByTagNameNS($slashNS, 'comments')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo '<br />'."\n";

            $desc = $item->getElementsByTagName('description');
            if ($desc->length > 0) {
             echo ' '.$desc->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
            }

            $lien = $item->getElementsByTagName('link');
            if ($lien->length >0) {
                echo ' <a href="'.$lien->item(0)->nodeValue.'">Article complet</a>';
         }


         echo '<br/>'."\n".'<br/>'."\n".'<br/>'."\n";   

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) the foreach loop when a counter reaches 10.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($itemList as $item) {
    $i++;
    // ...
    if($i>9){ break; }
}
```

Or, restructure into a for() loop, and surround ALL the code inside with an if() statement similar to above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now i have just 10 articles shown in my page but i don't have the other articles.
i want to show them in next pages.

Comment: That's a common feature called 'Pagination'. You should be able to find tons of things if you google 'pagination php'.

Comment: I'll search for it. Thanks !